# Understanding HTML Retina Canvas Support

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Recently I got into HTML `canvas` drawing and the retina support for it. Without further configuration lines drawn on a `canvas`-element look a little bit blurry on retina displays.

I do understand that the retina display has four times as much pixels and therefore has to fill some of the device pixels by default (otherwise the picture would be only half the size intended to).

**Example**:
Draw an HTML `canvas` with `width: 50px` and `height: 50px`.

`<canvas height="50px" width="50px">`

The browser on a *normal* screen just draws it (50*50 pixels). The browser on a retina display receives the 50x50px canvas, but since it is retina 50*50 device pixels would be smaller then intended. Therefore the browser draws it 100*100 pixels on retina.

A clear line (single pixel line black/white) on the canvas now becomes a little blurry, since the browser has to fill the nearby pixels and uses the nearby surrounding - some pixels turn out grey.

**How to fix it:**
Th piece of code should fix the problem:

```
// Returns: 1 on 'normal' screens, 2 on retina displays
var PIXEL_RATIO = (function () {
    var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
        dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

    return dpr / bsr;
})();


function makeCanvasHiPPI(canvas) {
  canvas.style.width  = canvas.width  + "px";
  canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";

  canvas.width  *= PIXEL_RATIO;
  canvas.height *= PIXEL_RATIO;

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.scale(PIXEL_RATIO, PIXEL_RATIO)
}
```

**What I think the code does:**
With this piece of code used on the canvas the browser is informed to use 50*50px (that is what the `canvas.style` is set to) as in the example above - 50*50px on normal screens, 100*100px on retinas. *But* it internally handles the canvas as an canvas of twice the size (at least on retina devices)and therefore is able to draw the pixels which are normally filled by the browser.

**The tricky part (I don't *quite* understand):**
The scaling. Double 'canvas.width'? Fine, now we have more pixels we can write to - more information. Good. 
But now it is scaled, therefore we don't *really* write to the extra pixel (only 0 - 50 will show up on the canvas) - who fills the device pixels this time? I tried it without the scaling and it allows me to draw thinner lines on retina (~1 device pixel) on the range 0 - 100 - these pixels are still a little bit blurry though, the scaled lines are thicker, but crystal clear. Fuzzy only visible with a lot of zoom.

**Pro scale:**

- crystal lines
- No scale somehow didn't produce a strong black in my example (visible under strong zoom)

**Pro no scale:**

- ability to draw *thin* lines
- `canvas.width` really represents the pixels I can write to. For example:

```
context.moveTo(0, context.canvas.height/2);
context.lineTo(context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height/2);
```

works. This doesn't work with scaling, since `context.canvas.width` returns unscaled values.

**My questions:**

- Why is the line clear with scaling, even though I don't even fill the *extra* pixels by myself?
- How would I go about the misleading  return value?
- Should I always use `context.canvas.width / PIXEL_RATIO` (with scaling)? This does fix the problem, but doesn't look nice in the code ([OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) kicks in).  I will go with this until I got something better though.

Comment: The reason that scaling works without becoming blurry is that it is the drawing math that is transformed before drawing on the native pixels, rather than drawing first then transforming the resulting pixels (which is essentially what the non-retina code does that causes the initial blurriness).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform

Answer (score 1):

1. The line might look clear without scaling because canvas has a high dpi backing store in your case: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/
2. I don't understand the question about misleading return values. Everything seems perfectly consistent. Have you tried to set the line width to 0.5 in the "unscaled" case?
3. It really depends on your use case. If "unscaled" is good enough, go for it. Otherwise, if you need control over DPI for your application, go for the high DPI approach.

Comment: With 'misleading' I mean that `context.canvas.width` returns for example 100 when I can only draw up to pixel 50. That is pretty misleading if you'd ask me.

Comment: And as you can see in the posted code, it actually already uses the backing store.

Comment: Printing `dpr` and `bsr` separately may resolve the confusion and better explain what is going on. You may want to add which browser you are using to the question, because Safari and Chrome handle the backing store differently.

Comment: I read the article as well, but it doesn't clear my questions. I'm on Safari (scales backing `backingStorePixelRatio` automatically). `devicePixelRatio = 2` (retina display), `backingStorePixelRatio = 1`.