# GWT Canvas and Retina Display scaling issue

Tags: canvas, gwt, retina-display

I need to apply GWT and html5 canvas. Since the html5 canvas is fully wrapped by gwt I'd also expect that I am able adjust to a retina display.

I searched the internet but didn't find any answer for GWT. So, the usual way to do this in javascript is to set the scale factor like this [Understanding HTML Retina Canvas Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820750/understanding-html-retina-canvas-support)

So, I tried the same in my gwt project and ended up with:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

        Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
        canvas.getElement().setAttribute("width", "800");
        canvas.getElement().setAttribute("height", "500");
        canvas.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("border", "black solid 1px");
        RootPanel.get("root").add(canvas);

        Context2d ctx = canvas.getContext2d();

        //For Retina Displays
        int dpi = dpi();
        ctx.scale(dpi, dpi);

        double posX = 10;
        double posY = 10;
        double width = 200;
        double height = 30;
        double cornerRadius = 2;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(posX+(width/2), posY);
        ctx.arcTo(posX+width, posY, posX+width, posY+(height/2), cornerRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(posX+width, posY+(height/2));
        ctx.arcTo(posX+width, posY+height, posX+(width/2), posY+height, cornerRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(posX+(width/2), posY+height);
        ctx.arcTo(posX, posY+height, posX, posY+(height/2), cornerRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(posX, posY+(height/2));
        ctx.arcTo(posX, posY, posX+(width/2), posY, cornerRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(posX+(width/2), posY);
        ctx.setStrokeStyle("rgba(255,255,255,1.0");
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.setShadowBlur(2);
        ctx.setShadowColor("rgba(0,0,0,0.5)");
        ctx.setShadowOffsetX(1);
        ctx.setShadowOffsetY(1);

        ctx.setFillStyle("white");
        ctx.fill();
    }


    public static native int dpi() /*-{
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820750/understanding-html-retina-canvas-support
        var ctx = $wnd.document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
        dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

        return dpr / bsr;
    }-*/;
```

However, it is not working. Instead, the rounded rectangle is just double the size now. The draw still looks pretty blurry.

How do I have to tweak the canvas in order to compensate for the plus of pixels on retina displays?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what is to do in order to get a sharp canvas with GWT and a Retina Display.

Same code as above, but with these changes:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

        int canvasWidth = 800;
        int canvasHeight = 500;
        Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
        canvas.setPixelSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        canvas.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("border", "black solid 1px");
        RootPanel.get("root").add(canvas);

        //In order to be sharp on a Retina Display, use the following code!
        Context2d ctx = createContext2DNatively(canvas.getElement(), canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        //Continue as you would normally do...
```

For some reason I could not figure out how to tweak this option in GWT. Thus I created it with native Javascript. The method looks like this:

```
public static native Context2d createContext2DNatively(Element canvas, int width, int height) /*-{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820750/understanding-html-retina-canvas-support
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

    var ratio = dpr / bsr;
    canvas.setAttribute('width', width*ratio);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', height*ratio);
    ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);
    return ctx;
}-*/;
```

This should solve the issue.

Comment: You still seem to be missing the style size changes - and the `setAttribute("width", "800")` code in the question itself could have been edited to pass in `width*ratio` in java rather than waiting until the JSNI method. Also keep in mind that JSNI will not be supported in GWT3, and rather than writing new JSNI now, it is better to write JsInterop instead.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I actually tried `canvas.setAttribute("width", "800")`. However, this did - surprisingly - not work. Therefore it is contained in the javascript native method. BTW: Style size is set in `canvas.setPixelSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);`

Comment: Hmm, very odd - it works for my projects, wonder what is different here... Glad you got it sorted!